# How to get the decimal ascii code of NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, ascii

With the method:

```
UniChar ch = (UniChar) [aInput characterAtIndex: i];
```

I get the ​​**ch** value is a hexadecimal code, how to get the decimal ascii code?  Is there a system approach？

Answer (score 1):

```
Char ch = [aInput characterAtIndex: i];

NSLog(@"%d", ch);
```

This gives you ascii value.

Comment: NO,i want get the 'ch' value, and not only to print out.Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Where do you want this value to ? an int? then, `int n = (int)ch;`

Answer (score 0):

> NO,i want get the 'ch' value, and not only to print out.Do you have some ideas?

Doesn't cast to UniChar. characterAtIndex return you decimal value